# Merge Person objects with similar attributes into a single Map Entry

Tags: java, java-stream

### Person.java

```
class Person{
    String name;
    Integer age;
    Integer salary;
    //...getter..setter
}
```

### List of Person objects:

```
List<Person> tempList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Person("John",33,10000), new Person("Peter",21,2000), new Person("John",18,5000), new Person("Peter",31,6000)));
```

Using java streams, how do I tell my program to 'Find all person with same name and perform SUM operations on their Ages and on their Salaries'

So desired outcome for this would be something like:

```
"John", 51, 1500
"Peter", 52, 8000
```

What I've tried:

```
Map<String,Integer> NameAndSalary= tempList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName,Collectors.summingInt(Person::getSalary) ));
```

---

```
Map<String,Integer> NameAndAge= tempList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName,Collectors.summingInt(Person::getAge) ));
```

This is good but this produce separate results like:

```
"John", 51
```

and

```
"John", 1500
```

Is there a shortcut to make it:

```
"John", 51, 1500
```

Comment: Basically, you want to merge two objects into one map entry.

Comment: Joona, what you described looks like a tuple. Java doesn't have tuples, so you will have to create one of your own. Fortunately, your `Person` object seems to fit the footprint of your "tuple". Sounds like you can create a "composite person" containing the name and the sum of their numeric attributes.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I'll look into this Tuples using Java style

Comment: @JoonaRitva I have a solution for you. Don't forget to mark it as the selected answer if I fully answered your question. I believe I did.

Comment: @JoonaRitva you do want to research the concept of tuples and how to leverage Java records to basically accomplish the same. You can see how simple this solution was if you really think about it. One thing to remember is that **Java records are _immutable_**. That is why I needed to create a new `Person` rather than mutate an existing person to store the sum of the ages and salaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, Java does not have tuples. The way you create a tuple, is to create a class that resembles one. The `Person` class already resembles a tuple. So, what I did was to create a Java record (the same as a Java POJO minus boilerplate code) and I collected the persons with the same name and summed up their ages and salaries to create a composite person with the same name. My solution:

```
public class TupleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = List.of(
                new Person("John",33,10000),
                new Person("Peter",21,2000),
                new Person("John",18,5000),
                new Person("Peter",31,6000));

        Collection<Person> result = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.name(),
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.reducing((Person p1, Person p2) -> new Person(p1.name(), p1.age() + p2.age(), p1.salary() + p2.salary())),
                        Optional::get))).values();

        result.forEach(person ->{
            System.out.println("Cumulative person: " + person);
        });

    }

    private static record Person(String name, int age, int salary){
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Name: " + name + ", age: " + age + ", salary: " + salary;
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Cumulative person: Name: John, age: 51, salary: 15000
Cumulative person: Name: Peter, age: 52, salary: 8000
```

What the code is doing is using a stream to collect, grouping by name, all the `Person` objects and will create a new `Person` composed of the previous match and the current match, where the name attribute is kept, and the ages and salaries are added up. It will continue to do this until the stream is totally consumed. So, to this example, if you were to add a new "Peter" with age of 48 and salary of 12000, it will create a "composite" Peter of age 100 and salary of 20000.